# Importing the right Popper.js version in Bootstrap when bundling with Rollup

Tags: bootstrap-5, rollupjs, popper.js

I am building a Rails 7 project with Rollup as JS bundler and Bootstrap (5.2.3) for styling.

When I try to use any of the Bootstrap modules which depend on Popper (2.11.7), I get an error because Bootstrap seems to imports the Node version of Popper which depends on `process`.

From the Popper docs (https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/#distribution-targets)

> There are two different esm builds, one for bundler consumers (e.g. webpack, Rollup, etc..), which is located under /lib, and one for browsers with native support for ES Modules, under /dist/esm. The only difference within the two, is that the browser-compatible version doesn't make use of process.env.NODE_ENV to run development checks.

In `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js`, Bootstrap imports Popper through

```js
import * as Popper from '@popperjs/core';
```

The same also goes for individual modules such as `node_modules/js/dist/dropdown.js`.

Running in the browser gives the following error message, showing that the imported Popper version is trying to access `process`.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    setOptions createPopper.js:81
    createPopper createPopper.js:215
    _createPopper bootstrap.esm.js:2186
    show bootstrap.esm.js:2077
    toggle bootstrap.esm.js:2060
    <anonymous> bootstrap.esm.js:2391
    handler bootstrap.esm.js:393
    addHandler bootstrap.esm.js:452
    on bootstrap.esm.js:485
    <anonymous> bootstrap.esm.js:2389
```

How do I get the import to resolve to the right Popper version? Manually changing the import in the node module solves the problem temporarily, but that will obviously not be a sustainable solution.